# Unity 2021.3.20 Built-in ShaderGraph 12.1.10 Fog Density inverted in linear fog and showing wrong fog colors on far objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fog, shader-graph

Unity Shader Graph Fog node shows density inverted when using Linear Fog. Also not properly showing the color of the fog on far objects.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems we are missing one step in the fog calculation. This custom node fix the issue.

**Custom node body:**

```
fogIntensity = 0;

#if defined(FOG_EXP)
    fogIntensity = 1 - saturate(exp2(-fogFactor));

#elif defined(FOG_EXP2)
    fogIntensity = 1 - saturate(exp2(-fogFactor * fogFactor));

#elif defined(FOG_LINEAR)
    fogIntensity = 1 - fogFactor;

#endif
```

**Custom node Settings:**

[image].

**Custom node usage:**

[image]

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

[image]